# Python/Shell script String issues

Tags: python, zsh

I'm trying to customize my `zsh` prompt. The function below calls a Python script and returns the entire working directory path minus just the current directory. E.g. `~/research` would go to `~`. This is a `.zsh-theme` file.

```
function collapse_pwd {
    echo $(python ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/truncatecwd.py '%~' '%c')
}
```

This is the python script, `truncatecwd.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

cwd = sys.argv[1]
current_dir_end = sys.argv[2]

sys.stdout.write(cwd[0: cwd.index(current_dir_end)])
```

Weird things happen here. I keep getting errors saying that `current_dir_end` can't be found in `cwd`. I think that it has something to do with string formatting. I printed out `cwd`, and it seems to be correct: `'~/.oh-my-zsh/themes'`. However, when I call length on it, I get `2`. Same goes for `current_dir_end`: I get length `2`. In fact, even `cwd = '~'` returns a length of `2`. Clearly, something subtle (but probably simple) is going on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's up with the bash tag?

Comment: I'd assume setting the prompt is the same in both shells.

Comment: bash and zsh are different enough that the bash tag here is not helpful. Removed.

Comment: Instead of `print x`, by the way, `print repr(x)` is more likely to be helpful.

Comment: ...that said, I don't see why you need Python for this at all. Parameter expansion capabilities that zsh inherited from ksh should be more than adequate.

Comment: `echo $(cmd)` is usually better written `cmd` unless you specifically require the shell to normalize spaces between tokens and/or expand wildcards in the output from `cmd`.

Comment: @tripleee, ...well, since this is zsh, it doesn't do those things (and thereby breaks POSIX compatibility). Horrible practice to be in if you wanted to actually write code that would work anywhere else, of course, and not great for efficiency either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, but wouldn't the following suffice, with no Python involved at all?

```
collapse_pwd() {
  local result=${1:-$PWD}
  if [[ $result = */* ]]; then
    result="${result%/*}"
  fi
  if [[ $result = "$HOME"/* ]]; then
    result="~/${result#$HOME/}"
  fi
  echo "$result"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just that I have no idea how to use shell script.

Comment: Is there a way to make the working directory in terms of `~` instead of `/home`?

Comment: Thanks so much! I am still curious as to why the string issues were happening in the python script though...

Answer (score 1):

could you do something like this:

```
import os
import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()
ret = os.path.sep.join(cwd.split(os.path.sep)[:-1])
sys.stdout.write(ret)
```

also, just an observation, because I'm not too familiar with zsh you may need to call python with -u option to ensure unbuffered output otherwise a newline may be written and that wouldn't be good with a command prompt.

Comment: Shells in general strip trailing newlines from command substitution output (and though zsh doesn't care much for POSIX compatibility, this is a place where it retains it).

Comment: Thanks, I did know that it was the case with most shells, but like I said I'm not too familiar with zsh (more of a bash and ksh guy). I up-voted the accepted answer because I believe in sticking to native solutions where possible, but I provided this answer because the op did ask about python and I thought it worth providing an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment above, but you said you were still currious about the string issues in python. I tested this on windows8 and CentOS 6.5, and it works beautifully. The only thing I could find was this:

     `These are deprecated as %c and %C are equivalent to %1~ and %1/, respectively`

which is from here:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html

Also you didn't mention the output of printing "current_dir_end". Is it possible that %c is not being expanded properly?